# Azure data studio : writing python with hints

Tags: python, azure-data-studio

In visual studio code , when I write python code , it can intelligently provide you hints .

for example

[image]

are there any similar things in Azure data studio ? thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure data studio, but this feature is called "IntelliSense",  check with Azure extension if you can find it :)

Comment: hi.. thanks but seems don't have it .